# Entity Framework 6.2 - add children with DbSet.Include() but prevent duplicate children on DbSet.AddRange()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-6, system.data.sqlite

EDIT:

**I know how to prevent duplicates when copying entities from one DbContext to another, my question is about their children.**

---

I have two contexts: `DbContextHDD` and `DbContextUSB` and they both contain a "Math" `Course`.

`DbContextHDD` also contains:

- a "History" `Course`.
- a `Student` "Simon" who attends "Math" `Course`.
- a `Student` "Jack" who attends "History" `Course`.

**I would like to copy all `Student` entities from `DbContextHDD` to `DbContextUSB` and also include any `Course` entities not already present in `DbContextUSB`:**

```
var students = DbContextHDD.Students.Include(s => s.Courses).ToList();
DbContextUSB.Students.AddRange(students);
DbContextUSB.SaveChanges();
```

This also copies "Math" and "History" `Course` entities from `DbContextHDD` to `DbContextUSB`.

After `Students.AddRange` I have two "Math" `Course` entities in `DbContextUSB.Courses.Local`, both with the same `CourseId` and `SaveChanges` fails with `SQLiteException: UNIQUE constraint failed`.

## **How can I avoid that?**

---

I am using the Code-First approach. Proxy creation is disabled:

```
Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

I have a many to many relationship:

```
public class Student
{
    public Student() 
    {
        this.Courses = new HashSet<Course>();
    }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public Course()
    {
        this.Students = new HashSet<Student>();
    }

    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: my previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57180967/entity-framework-6-2-copy-many-to-many-from-one-dbcontext-to-another-dbcontext

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to apply a filter?

```cs
var targetStudentIds = DbContextUSB.Students.Select(s => s.StudentId).ToArray();
var sourceStudents = DbContextHDD.Students.Include(s => s.Courses).Where(s => !targetStudentIds.Contains(s.StudentId)).ToArray();

DbContextUSB.Students.AddRange(sourceStudents);
```

Comment: I want to prevent duplicate children (Course) of the entity (Student). Your solution prevents duplicate entities (Student), but not duplicates of their children (Course).